# how to count the top_topics based on number of groups created on that topic in django?

Tags: python, django

I have such models where topic is related with room as shown in code. How can i count the top_topics as i have counted in top_groups. I want to count top_topics based on number of group created on that topic. I hope you get what i mean.

**Models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Room(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    group_photo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to = 'images/', default='avatar.svg')
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta: 
       ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

**Views.py**

```
def home(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else ''
    groups = Room.objects.filter(Q(topic__name__icontains=q)|
                                Q(name__icontains=q) |
                                Q(description__icontains=q)
                                )

    top_groups = Room.objects.alias(
        num_members = Count('members')
    ).order_by('-num_members')[:5]

    group_count = groups.count()
    
    topics = Topic.objects.all()[:5]

    context = {'groups':groups, 'group_count':group_count, 'topics':topics, 'top_groups':top_groups}
    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)
```

I am basically confused in relationship. what can be the way i can access Room from Topic? Please help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly access the count of groups related to each topic by:

```py
topic.room_set.count()
```

This is when you access each topic individually. If you want to put it onto the queryset then use `annotate()` and `Count()`.

Comment: i want to count in views not in template

Comment: You can do both `topic.room_set.count()` in views and `topic.room_set.count` in template